# GoogleSignIn ApiException: 10 with GoogleAuth not firebase (App with flavours)

Tags: android, google-authentication

> UPDATE: I forgot to say that the my app has multiple flavours.

I'm trying to login in my app with Google Aut(not with firebase). So, first, I'm using this dependencie:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
```

The app is a little bit old so they use old dependecies because of that.

Then I used this documentation to integrate the Google Sign-In in my app:

I have this method which is call on the onCreate in my activity:

```
public void createGoogleSignInOption() {
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken("abcd")
            .build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
}
```

Then I have my Intent:

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 22);
}
```

In my activityResult I catch the response:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (callbackManager != null) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    if (requestCode == 22) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}
```

And finally I have this method according to the documentation

```
private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        Log.w("LOG", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

I also configured the proyect in the console and I have my credentials but nothing works. Btw, I already add my SHA1 to my configuration but still doesnt work.

The message is APIEXCEPTION 10.

Any idea? I'm stuck here like two days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I finally found the solution for my problem. For all those people who work with flavours in your android app.

> **YOU MUST PUT YOUR CURRENT FLAVOUR PACKAGE**

For example, when I tried to configure the project, I register the package "com.abcde.fg" instead of "dev.com.abcde.fg". I changed that and FINALLY my app works.

Hope this help somebody.

Happy code!

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue because of **SHA** key. You need to generate a **SHA** key from your system then put in console.then is issue resolved.
you can also generate **SHA** key from android studio,

first of open project then click on **gradle** which is located at right side of vertical bar,
then **select project-> app module -> Task -> android -> signing report. then you get SHA key**.

Comment: I am created a below library for social integration. Can u try your key in this library and test it. i think this will help you
https://github.com/webaddicted/EasySocialLogin